# Cannot generate DB from EDMX - XAML file does not exist

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

In an EF project with an EDMX entity model, when I right click and hit *Generate database from Model...* I get the error:

> An exception occurred while attempting to generate the database script from the model because the specified workflow file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\Generate T-SQL Via T4 (TPH).xaml' does not exist.

No XAML files featuring the word 'generate' exist at all on my hard disk. I thought I installed all I need with VS 2013 and the NuGet packages.

I also installed **Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013** but no XAML files were added, the error still appears.

On MSDN, the generate database wizard is discussed under **ADO.NET Entity Data Model Tools** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399249(v=vs.100).aspx) but I can't find it to download online or from the VS extensions 'store'.

In Windows Programs and Features I have these items containing "entity":

- Entity Framework 6.1.2 Tools for Visual Studio 2013
- Entity Framework Designer for Visual Studio 2012 -enu

What am I missing?

Comment: Beginning to work this out for myself, will post an answer if I sort it. That XAML file is hard to Google. Trying to see if the TPH strategy was 'retired' in favour of TPT and thus a different XAML file...

Answer (score 0):

I think my old project was set to use TPH but that strategy is no longer available, or was never available and I forgot that I installed the Powerpack to get it. Or maybe never used TPH.

This quote is interesting from a blog:

"Got the EF Powerpack that allowed generating TPH mappings." - http://www.jefim.eu/blog/2013/01/entity-framework-tpt-vs-tph.html

PowerPack here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87

I seem to recall (I have been on a no-sql contract for years and last touched EF in v4) that I didn't like Table-per-Hierarchy and should be using Table-per-Type. I get the feeling that in the last couple of years, this has become the general feeling in EF or perhaps model-first was 'de-emphasised' in favor of code-first, which does support TPH and does database generation some other way? Guessing.

So I think the answer is that:

With Model-first, TPH is not available, use TPT.

If TPH is really wanted, then use the PowerPack (though it says VS2010) or maybe go code-first.